# Magento 2: Why are there Multiple Calls to `_.extend`

Tags: magento2, javascript, underscorejs

The underscore javascript library contains a method named `extend`.  You can use extend to copy properties of one javascript object to another javascript object in a consistent way.  These properties can be data, or javascript functions.

Magento 2 uses this to give objects methods.  You can see any example of this here

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/core/renderer/layout.js
_.extend(layout, {
    iterator: function (parent, node) {
    //...
});
```

By copying the `interator` property to the `layout` object, the underscore JS library gives the layout object an `interator` method.

What I don't understand is why Magento ends calling extend multiple times.  From the same file.

```
_.extend(layout, {
    iterator: function (parent, node) {
    //...
});

_.extend(layout, {
    waitTemplate: function (parent, node) {
    //...
});

_.extend(layout, {
    manipulate: function (node) {
    //...
});
```

I get that each of these `extend` calls copies a different set of properties -- but is there a compelling technical reason Magento's core developers have spread these out into three different calls?  Or is this just style (possibly laziness/busyness) showing its hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research, this appears to be nothing more than the team's personal style/quirks.  The three different calls to extend seem to group methods by functionality

```
Main App Methods:       iterator, process, build, initComponent
Async Methods:          waitTemplate, waitParent, applyTemplate
Data Get/Set Methods:   manipulate, insert, insertTo, addChild, merge,
                        getDataSources, getFullConfig, getByProperty,
                        filterComponents
```

However, there's nothing in this separation that effects the actual behavior of the `layout` object.  Its just a team choice as to how things are organized.